# What's the definition of Font Asset in the Asset Catalog?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, core-text, asset-catalog

Starting from iOS 13, `CTFontManager` has the following function:

```
@discussion Font assets are extracted from the asset catalog and registered. This call must be made after the completion handler of either NSBundleResourceRequest beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler: or conditionallyBeginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler: is called successfully.
Name the assets using Postscript names for individual faces, or family names for variable/collection fonts. The same names can be used to unregister the fonts with CTFontManagerUnregisterFontDescriptors. In iOS, fonts registered with the persistent scope are not automatically available to other processes. Other process may call CTFontManagerRequestFonts to get access to these fonts.

@param      fontAssetNames
            Array of font name assets in asset catalog.

...

CTFontManagerRegisterFontsWithAssetNames(_ fontAssetNames: CFArray, _ bundle: CFBundle?, _ scope: CTFontManagerScope, _ enabled: Bool, _ registrationHandler: ((CFArray, Bool) -> Bool)?)
```

However, Asset Catalog does not have any way to add "Font Assets".

What I've tried:

- took font `KanitRegular.ttf` (PostScript name is `Kanit-Regular`) [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Kanit?preview.text_type=custom).
- created Data Asset named `Kanit-Regular` in the asset catalog.
- Renamed font file to `Kanit-Regular.ttf` and put it into the data asset.

Data Asset's `Contents.json` now looks like this:

```
{
   "data" : [
    {
      "filename" : "Kanit-Regular.ttf",
      "idiom": "universal",
      "universal-type-identifier" : "public.truetype-ttf-font"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "author" : "xcode",
    "version" : 1
  }
}
```

- Tried to load this font via `CTFontManager`

like this:

```
func registerFont() {
    var cfBundle: CFBundle?
    if let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self)) {
        cfBundle = CFBundleCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, bundle.bundleURL as CFURL)
    }
    CTFontManagerRegisterFontsWithAssetNames(["Kanit-Regular"] as CFArray, cfBundle, .persistent, true) { (errors, done) -> Bool in
        print(errors)
        return done
    }
}
```

After this, getting `errors` printed:

```
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=22 "Invalid argument" UserInfo={CTFontManagerErrorFontAssetNameKey=(
    "Kanit-Regular"
)}
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working by making the following:

- Tag the `Kanit-Regular` data asset with `fonts` On-Demand Resource Tag (tag name can be the name of your preference, `fonts` is just the example).
- Put `fonts` tag into `Initial Install Tags` Prefetched Resource Tags section

[image: Initial Install Tags Resource Tags section]

- Add `Fonts` Capability in `Signing & Capabilities` and tick all boxes in it

[image]

- Implement bundle resource access request before registering fonts

like this:

```
func registerFont() {
    var cfBundle: CFBundle?
    var resourceRequest: NSBundleResourceRequest?
    if let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self)) {
        resourceRequest = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: Set(arrayLiteral: "fonts"), bundle: bundle)
        cfBundle = CFBundleCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, bundle.bundleURL as CFURL)
    }
    resourceRequest?.beginAccessingResources() { error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            CTFontManagerRegisterFontsWithAssetNames(["Kanit-Regular"] as CFArray, cfBundle, .persistent, true) { (errors, done) -> Bool in
                print(errors)
                return done
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Outcome**

When scope is passed as `.persistent` or `.user`, on initial call of `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsWithAssetNames` function the user will be asked to install fonts into the system, which is not what I really need. In case the scope is `.process` or `.none`, the same `errors` output is returned as provided at the end of the question.

Although this function does not fit my needs, I at least validated that it is working. Maybe someone finds it useful.